# How to backtrace slowness of a shared hosting web server

Tags: performance, web-server, web-hosting, performance-monitoring, shared-hosting

I have a shared hosting plan (godaddy), and time to time I suffer slowness problem. When this happens, I try to login to cpanel to double check if the problem is me or the server, and it also takes 1-2 minutes to enter cpanel.

As all customer service personal, they also lack of technical knowledge and always tries to persuade me the problem is on my side, and want me to remove browser cache.

I am telling them that this is a recurring problem, and I am trying to find a root cause, but they are not looking for a solution, and telling me everything seems fine on their side.

What can I do to backtrace this issue when I suffer this slowness so that when I call the customer service next time, I can show them some proving data, so they can actually work a little bit! .

P.S: There is no development on my website. Just updating the web shop products.

Comment: You need to get performance data on everything you think is slow.
response to website slow? great, log every visits response time, graph them, see the difference, send the graphs to the hosting provider.
Or the cheaper and faster  alternative: go get your own dedicated managed server (or rootserver if you have a sysadmin)

Please additionally see and read the help as the question in my opinion has at least a few possible reasons to be closed. (control panel access beeing the obvious one)
https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is simply this. Shared hosting. cPanel runs on its own in a separate process, not tied to Apache. If they're not using stuff like CloudLinux to limit the amount of CPU/memory users can use, this is most likely the sign you're on an overcrowded server. You get this in shared hosting all the time. I've worked in that industry for more than 5 years and honestly, your only options are below:

1) ask them to move you to a server and hope that server is not as overcrowded (or won't get overcrowded)
2) upgrade to a higher plan 
3) upgrade to a VPS/dedicated server (which I'm sure will come up in your discussions)

Sadly, being on a shared hosting there are not too many options. They will try and talk you into installing a caching system for Wordpress (which you should have, but because cPanel is also slow, highly doubt it's your website) or buy one of their packages to 'optimize' the website.

I honestly think getting a VPS (i.e. your own virtual server, completely isolated from the others) is your best option here, simply because of shared servers overcrowding.

Comment: They manage the cpanel, right?  Which means that there's nothing you can do to fix the problem.  This is their problem and they need to fix it.  I'm agreeing with the sentiment here that it's probably over provisioning for your shared host.  If you can, try this from another computer/location when the problem is happening.  When they tell you the problem is on your side you can confirm to them you've tried accessing from another PC on another network connection and the problem persists.  It won't help you track down the problem, but it will help get them to fix something their problem.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't actually answer the actual question, but I think this should help with solving the actual problem.

The problem might well be in your web shop software, which simply is slow when there is enough traffic.

You need to look at your traffic and check if high traffic ccorrelates with slowness. If there is correlateion, then it is the software that is slow.

Although GoDaddy has a reputation not being the best option for hosting, I assume they still do manage and monitor their resources in a good way, and that they don't overprovision their servers. Therefore software is more likely the culprit for slowness.

To actually solve your problem of web site slowness, in general level there are two options:

1. Look if there are ways to improve the web shop performance. Does it implement proper data caching? Does it implement database feature correctly?
2. Get a more powerful hosting package. More CPU, more RAM.

Comment: Hi Tero, thanks for your help, but traffic is not the reason. My website is getting average 100 daily visitors. It's like no traffic at all. Also my website gets slow randomly, and at that time it is also not possible to enter cpanel. Also there is no development in the website. The slowness occurs at totally random times . The website is WordPress based. Here I am trying to find the root cause, the two options you mention are not for finding the root cause. I am looking for a way to measure response times of a server or any other ways. This is the knowledge I lack, and I am looking for here.